# Datatables Row Grouping Stop Expanding When Input Clicked

Tags: jquery, datatables, stoppropagation

Using datatables and row grouping I am trying to get the rows to not expand when a input is clicked.. but only expand when the tr is clicked.    `.stopPropagation()` isn't working.

I am using `.live()` because the table is dynamically created by ajax.

```
$("#example input[type='text']").live('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JWvZt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While troubleshooting, it took me a while to find that you had your click event bound **twice** in your jsfiddle (at the beginning and at the end of the javascript frame).
After removing the first one and defining the 2nd as:

```
$("#example td").on('click','input[type="text"]', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

the code works as desired.
Note: I'm using .on() because .live() is deprecated. In order to refresh the event bindings, when you dynamically create your rows you will have to call the above code fragment in the AJAX success handler (or .done() method).

Here's a [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/uJZSu/2/)

Comment: Out of curiousity ... any idea why this doesn't work (same code - different order)? http://jsfiddle.net/ckhXp/  If the on click is before the datatables load, the on click doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I guess the reason is that the plugin rebuilds the td cells, so that the event bindings get lost.  Btw. returning false from the click handler is sufficient to stop the propagation (the stopPropagation() call can be skipped)